# Longest palindrome in a given string using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, palindrome

Problem:I need to write an algorithm that will return length of longest possible palindrome from a given string.

So if the input is aabbbccdfg
Program output should be 7. //-->[cabbbac]

Can someone point it out if there are any problems with below code?

```
public static void GetLongestPalindromeLength()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
        var result = 0;
        var countsByChar = input.GroupBy(c => c);
        var oddCounts = countsByChar.Where(g => g.Count() % 2 != 0).Select(g => g.Count()).ToList();
        var evenCounts = countsByChar.Where(g => g.Count() % 2 == 0).Select(g => g.Count()).ToList();
        if (oddCounts.Any())
        {
            var max = oddCounts.Max();
            result += max;
            oddCounts.RemoveAt(oddCounts.FindIndex(e => e == max));
            result += evenCounts.Sum();
            result += oddCounts.Sum(e => e - 1);
        }
        else if (evenCounts.Any())
        {
           result += evenCounts.Sum();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but to me your algorithm is plain wrong if I understand the problem correctly. Could you provide some test cases?

Comment: I tried with several palindromes found online. e.g ROTAVATOR ->9,dad->3,malayalam->9

Comment: and the case where it fails?

Comment: I'm not able to create one. :(

Comment: Well, so what's the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for all cases. is this algorithm correct? Grouping chars by their count, For odd counts take the maximum count, add sum of even counts and add rest of the odd counts minus one. If all counts are even then simply add'm up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think your algorithm is correct, but the code is quite bloat. Your code suggest that the longest palindrome size can be calculated by sum of `n / 2 * 2` where `n` is the count of distinct alphabet that exists more than once in the string, and plus 1 if there are any "oddCounts". So you can reduce the code to

```
    private static int GetLongestPalindrome(string value) {
        var map = value.GroupBy(c => c);
        int result = map.Sum(r => r.Count() / 2 * 2);
        if (map.Any(r => r.Count() % 2 != 0))
        {
            result++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

`n / 2 * 2` is the way to calculate for the nearest even number toward zero, and it equals to `n - 1` where `n` is positive odd number.

Comment: I think above code is not correct. e.g. for kkkkk output is 3 instead of 5. for MALAYALAM output is 7 instead of 9.

Comment: My bad. I fixed the bug already.